# How to report standard deviation while averaging a dataset multiple times?

Tags: standard-deviation, spatial, mean

This question appears simple but it may not be. I have a year long, 1 degree, daily, 3-d global climate data set (temperature) representing different latitude, longitude, and days. That means the data set has a size of 180*360*365. First, I calculated the longitudinally-averaged mean by averaging the data along the second dimension. That means I now have a data of size 180*365. I then again averaged the data along the latitude which gave me a globally averaged time-series data having 365 data. So my question is, how do I report the standard deviation of this final global mean that I calculated? Or better posed, how do I characterize the uncertainty of this global mean data that I calculated? At each step of averaging along longitude and latitude, I obviously have corresponding standard deviations. I am not expecting an ambiguous answer with all the mathematical details but a clear answer with insights into the problem.

Comment: It might be wise to re-examine the calculation. Its most problematic feature is that the cells represent radically varying amounts of the earth's surface: some are hundreds of times larger than others. This calls into question the scientific meaningfulness of these averages. If they aren't meaningful, then what good will standard deviations be?

Comment: That is how globally-averaged climate parameters are calculated, for example, global temperature.

Comment: No competent scientist would do it that way, because such a calculation depends on an arbitrary, high-distortion projection of the globe.  Its output therefore has no evident scientific meaning.  For example, in their pioneering paper (*Global Trends of Measured Surface Air Temperature*, J. Geo. Res. **92** No. #11 pp 13345-13372, 1987) James Hansen and Sergej Lebedeff divided the world into "80 regions of equal area" to compute their global averages: see their Figure 2.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I agree that looking at the regional variation is very much important and is much more meaningful. However, my question is different and not particular about global averaging. My question is pertinent in any problems involving averaging in two dimensions. So lets not focus on the climate part here.

Comment: Fair enough.  Let's explore why you are doing these operations, then.  Could you explain what they are intended to mean?  What is the purpose of reporting a standard deviation?  Why do you perform the averaging in two steps?  Since we're not talking about climate data any more, we also need guidance concerning its structure. For instance, the nature and extent of spatial correlation may play an important role. What can you say about that?  And are we still talking about data on a sphere or not?

Comment: Whenever some 'mean' is calculated by averaging, we have standard deviation. Standard deviation is commonly reported (often with error bars or shaded error bars) to show variability in measurements. I am sure you have seen many such time-series curves with error bars showing the variability in data. So my question is when the data is averaged in two dimensions (or twice), what is the best way to show this 'two-dimensional' variability. Yes, we are still talking about the data on a sphere or in 3 dimension.

Comment: The concern is that phenomena in space (whether on the sphere, the plane, or in three dimensions) commonly exhibit spatial autocorrelation. (A climatological dataset will typically exhibit strong amounts of correlation.)  Although you can compute standard deviations, if you attempt to use them to infer properties of the system you are studying, they can be highly biased. I'm trying to make sure you're not falling into that trap.

Comment: Okay! I got your point. For sure, there will be some spatial correlations specially among adjacent grid cells. I can calculate spatial cross correlations to look at that but that would be exhaustive for a global data. May be it is more efficient to do EOF analysis that would identify the spatial patterns where correlations would be high/low. Do you have more suggestions?